# python 3: how to make strip() work for bytes

Tags: python-3.x

I've contered a Python 2 code to Python 3.
In doing so, I've changed

```
print 'String: ' + somestring
```

into

```
print(b'String: '+somestring)
```

because I was getting the following error:

```
Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly
```

But then now I can't implement string attributes such as strip(), because they are no longer treated as strings...

```
global name 'strip' is not defined
```

for

```
if strip(somestring)=="":
```

How should I solve this dilemma between switching string to bytes and being able to use string attributes? Is there a workaround?
Please help me out and thank you in advance..

Comment: sorry it's actually not an empty string i fixed it

Comment: so it should work with bytes? i'm assuming using it in a standalone way is not supported in python 3? How should I fix it equivalently?

Comment: There's no `strip()` builtin in Python 2, either.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are two issues here, one of which is the actual issue, the other is confusing you, but not an actual issue. Firstly:

Your string is a bytes object, ie a string of 8-bit bytes. Python 3 handles this differently from text, which is Unicode. Where do you get the string from? Since you want to treat it as text, you should probably convert it to a str-object, which is used to handle text. This is typically done with the .decode() function, ie:

```
somestring.decode('UTF-8')
```

Although calling str() also works:

```
str(somestring, 'UTF8')
```

(Note that your decoding might be something else than UTF8)

However, this is not your actual question. Your actual question is how to strip a bytes string. And the asnwer is that you do that the same way as you string a text-string:

```
somestring.strip()
```

There is no strip() builtin in either Python 2 or Python 3. There is a strip-function in the string module in Python 2:

```
from string import strip
```

But it hasn't been good practice to use that since strings got a strip() method, which is like ten years or so now. So in Python 3 it is gone.

Comment: Note that when you pass an argument to `strip` (or `rstrip` or `lstrip`), the argument type needs to match the object type. That is, when you call `strip` on a `bytes` object, the argument can't be a string. This tripped me up when I called `s.rstrip('\0')` to remove trailing null characters. I needed to change it to `s.rstrip(b'\0')` because `s` was a `bytes` object, not a `str`.

Answer (score 7):

```
>>> b'foo '.strip()
b'foo'
```

Works just fine.

If what you're dealing with is text, though, you probably should just have an actual `str` object, not a `bytes` object.

Comment: However, `b'foo '.strip(' ')` failed; `b'foo '.strip(b' ')` worked.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you can use the "str" function to cast it to a string

```
print str(somestring).strip()
```

or maybe

```
print str(somestring, "utf-8").strip()
```

Comment: There is no casting in Python -- you get a new, different, object back.

Comment: true, str(object) returns a string. it's actually a new string object.

Answer (score 0):

However, if the object is already a string, you don't get a new one.  So if you're not sure whether an object is a string and need it to be and call str(obj), you won't create another if it's already a string.

```
x='123'
id(x)
2075707536496
y=str(x)
id(y)
2075707536496
```