# Stripping newlines off of read file doesn't work

Tags: python-3.x, file-io

I have a function that is supposed to read a file as bytes and strip off newline characters, but when I try to use .strip() it gives me the error `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`, so then I try to encode it using `.encode('utf-8')` before stripping, and I get `AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'`. I don't really know where to begin with this problem. Here's the code:

```
file = open(str(filename + ".data"), "rb")
file.seek(0)
array = file.readlines()
b = array[lineNumber].strip('\n\r')
```

The file is encrypted bytes that I'm trying to feed into a decryption function to get ascii.

Comment: You're opening a text file, you shouldn't use "rb" mode - the b means bytes, just use "r"

Comment: I'm not actually using a text file, I accidentally copied the wrong part of my code.

Answer (score 0):

[This comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9560759/python-3-how-to-make-strip-work-for-bytes#comment42542074_9562196) showed me that I needed to use `.strip()` with bytes instead of a string: `.strip(b'\n\r')` instead of `.strip('\n\r')` since I was stripping bytes.